# When $L(H)=L(G)$ :: When the line graph of the hypergraph $H$ is a line graph of some multigraph $G$ ??

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraphs, multigraphs

**Introduction:**
The line graph of a hypergraph is the graph whose vertex set is the set of the hyperedges of the hypergraph $\{E_1,...E_m\}$, with two hyperedges adjacent when they have
a nonempty intersection.

-$L(H) \subset G$ :: any graph is the line graph of some hypergraph,
but the opposite case is NOT always true (that is, not  any hypergraph is the line graph of some graph).

Example:  $K_{1,3}$ is the line graph of the hypergraph $(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},$ $\{\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}, \{v_1\}, \{v_2\}, \{v_3\}\})$ but by [Beineke's characterization of line graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Forbidden_subgraphs)
it is not the line graph of any graph.

**Question?**
Is there is any condition on the hypergraph $H$ (even in very special cases) such that $L(H)=L(G),$ that is the line graph of the hypergraph $H$ is also a line graph of some multigraph $G$.

Any idea will be useful!

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Characterization_and_recognition), “a graph $L$ is the line graph of some other graph or multigraph if and only if it is possible to find a collection of cliques in $L$ (allowing some of the cliques to be single vertices) that partition the edges of $L$, such that each vertex of $L$ belongs to exactly two of the cliques”. Or you are interested in conditions imposed on a hypergraph under which its line graph is a line graph of some multigraph?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you! I wonder if there is a similar work for the hypergraph case. Yes, I am more interested in the condition imposed on the hypergraph H  such that: L(H)=L(G), or H=L(G) for some multigraph G.

Comment: The case $H=L(G)$ is already considered above. In this case $H$ is a graph  satisfying the above conditions.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you! In fact, I am mainly looking for the case $L(H)=L(G)$.